# why ListView does not filled while I am using AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

I am writing an app that uses Google book search API , what the app suppose to do is to display a list of books based on a search query that i provide within the app's code as a String, i use an AsyncTask inner class to handle the background work (making HTTP request , JSON formatting ...etc), I also have book costume adapter and book class to get the data from , my problem is the app dose not display any book in the list view .

**here's my code:**

> My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final static String bookUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android&maxResults=6";
    private BookAdapter bookAdapter;

    private ArrayList<Book> books;

    private ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


         list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
         new BookAsynck().execute(bookUrl);


    }

    private class BookAsynck extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Book>> {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Book> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            books = Utils.fetchBookData(bookUrl);
            return books;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Book> books) {
            bookAdapter = new BookAdapter(MainActivity.this, books);
            list.setAdapter(bookAdapter);
        }
    }

}
```

---

> My Util class :

```
    public class Utils {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = Utils.class.getSimpleName();


    public static ArrayList<Book> fetchBookData(String requestUrl) {

        ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();

        URL url = CreateURl(requestUrl);
        String json = null;
        try {
            json = makeHttpRequest(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing input stream", e);
        }
        bookList = extractBookData(json);
        return bookList;
    }


    public static URL CreateURl(String stringUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error with creating URL ", e);
        }
        return url;
    }

    //make http  request and return a string containing the response
    public static String makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = "";
        //if the url is null return empty string
        if (url == null) {
            return jsonResponse;
        }

        HttpURLConnection urlcon = null;
        InputStream inputstream = null;
        try {
            urlcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlcon.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlcon.setReadTimeout(1000 /*milleseconds*/);
            urlcon.setConnectTimeout(1500 /*milleseconds*/);
            urlcon.connect();
//if the request wass Successul (code 200)
            // get the input stream and decode it

            if (urlcon.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputstream = urlcon.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputstream);
            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code " + urlcon.getResponseCode());

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the book JSON results", e);
        } finally {
            if (urlcon != null) {
                urlcon.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputstream != null) {
                inputstream.close();
            }
        }

        return jsonResponse;
    }


//decode the inputstream into string that conatin the Jsresponse from the Server


        private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    output.append(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
            }
            return output.toString();
        }

        public static ArrayList<Book> extractBookData(String json) {
            ArrayList<Book> booklist = new ArrayList<>();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(json)) {
                return null;
            }

            try {
                JSONObject base = new JSONObject(json);
                JSONArray itemsArray = base.optJSONArray("items");

                for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject first = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject volume = new JSONObject("volumeInfo");
                    String title = volume.getString("title");
                    JSONArray authorsArray = volume.getJSONArray("authors");
                    String author = authorsArray.getString(0);

                    Book b = new Book(title, author);
                    booklist.add(b);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem parsing the book JSON results", e);
            }
            return booklist;
        }
    }
```

---

> My Book Adapter:

```
    public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {
    public BookAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Book> book) {
        super(c, 0, book);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View list = convertView;
        if (list == null) {
            list = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

        }
        Book b = getItem(position);

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) list.findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleTextView.setText(b.getName());

        TextView author = (TextView) list.findViewById(R.id.author);
        author.setText(b.getAuthor());


        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: do not put your whole code in your question I recommend you see this [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed calling your asynctask inside activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
new BookAsynck().execute(bookUrl);
}
```

Comment: i tried it and i got this error   :java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: remove Listview declaration again  in oncreate i edited my code

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow !!

Beginning at Android 9, requests without encryption will not work, that means **HttpsURLConnection** will work but **HttpURLConnection** will not.

Then the URL you try to connect must have a https:// access or you should include this in your manifest

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: still nothing happened

Comment: how to make this encryption in the request

Comment: HttpsURLConnection does the encryption, but as I said the URL web site must be a secure site, must be a https:// site, not http:// and of course your URL must begin with https:// Put breakpoints in all your catch() and look at the Exception message

Comment: my mistake was here:books = Utils.fetchBookData(bookUrl); , insted of (bookUrl) , i added (string[0]), and it worked , thanks for asking

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line from `onCreate()`

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

to

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Comment: still nothing displayed

Comment: @linasaeed did you debug and check whether you get a list of items until setting to the ListView Adapter?

Comment: yeah , my mistake was here:books = Utils.fetchBookData(bookUrl);  , insted of bookUrl ,  i added string[0], and it worked , thanks for asking